# Is $H(k \operatorname\| H(k \operatorname\| m))$​ with double length $k$ like NMAC?

Tags: hmac, mac

I know that NMAC is mathematically proved with two different keys with length $L$.

But, if I choose to implement a MAC this way: $$H(k \operatorname\| H(k \operatorname\| msg))$$ with a key $k$ of length ​$2L$, ​am I vulnerable to some attacks?

Comment: But you'd still use the same key both times in there?

Comment: Yes, I think this way i'm vulnerable to length extension attack (if implemented with markle-damgard), Am I right?

Comment: Length-extension attacks don't apply here, given that the outer layer has constant input length. This construction is equivalent to the $\text{NMAC}_3$ construction studied in https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/649. Its exact security is unknown.

Comment: @SamuelNeves In that case it's an answer :) We're not supposed to do original research to get to an answer here.